# unable to specify custom Django Model from nested app as AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django

I am unable to specify a custom `AUTH_USER_MODEL` if that model is in a *nested* application.

Here is some project structure:

```
├── project
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── my_parent_app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   └── my_child_app
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── apps.py
│   │       └── models.py
```

and here is some code:

**project/my_parent_app/my_child_app/models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
  is_a_nice_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**project/settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'my_parent_app',
  'my_parent_app.my_child_app',
]  
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_parent_app.my_child_app.User'
```

When I try to do anything, I get this error:

> ValueError: Invalid model reference 'my_parent_app.my_child_app.User'. String
>   model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.

This is a very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583616/auth-user-model-does-not-accept-sub-application). But how can I solve this without resorting to making `my_child_app` a separate top-level app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AUTH_USER_MODEL` has to be in the format `app_label.model_name`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_parent_app',
    'my_parent_app.my_child_app',
]  
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_child_app.User'
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works. The reason this _hadn't_ been working was that `my_child_app` was actually called `users` which, presumably, conflicted w/ an existing Django app_label.